# How to rationalize the numerator of $\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}-\sqrt[3]{a}}{x-a}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I found this question on Schaum's Outline of precalculus, but don't know how to get to the corret answer. This is driving me insane. Please help.

The question:
$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}-\sqrt[3]{a}}{x-a}$$

It supposed to be:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{xa}+\sqrt[3]{a^2}}$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: write $y=\sqrt[3]{x}$ and $b=\sqrt[3]{a}$. Then $x= y^3$ and ...